# iPhone calendar app for multiple gmail accounts

Tags: iphone, google-calendar, google

I have the gmail app which lets me sync my work and personal gmail accounts. I want to be able to sync both google accounts with a calendar app as well. The default calendar only supports one. I installed calenmob and its really nice but also only supports one google account. Is there a calendar app that will let me sync 2 google accounts?

I am using an iPhone 5 with iOS 6.1

Comment: What do you mean with "the default calendar only supports one"? Just create a second Google account in the preferences and it will also show your work calendar in the calendar app.

Comment: @cyphorious that worked thanks (sorry I am new to this phone)

Comment: OK. In this case I post it as an answer again.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any third party app to add different calendars to the built-in app. Just open the iOS preferences, go to *Mail, Contacts, Calendars* and add another account of your choice. In your case, just add another Google account.

Answer (score 0):

I have a work gmail account and a personal gmail account and I can only see one calendar at a time on my iPhone. They are both entered, and I get email from both accounts, but I cannot see calendar events from both calendars. So I use CalenGoo app.

Comment: Can you explain what CalenGoo is and what makes it work for you?